# Error tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] occurred when I run my LSTM model in spyder python after some iterations

Tags: python, tensorflow, cpu, spyder

An error occurred while starting the kernel

```
2020 08:37:22.140336: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations: AVX AVX2

To enable them in non MKL DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

2020 08:37:22.144012: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 4. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
```

Comment: Code formatting correction and sentence correction.

Comment: Title correction.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Those error messages seem clear enough to me.

Comment: how to resolve this error ? @AMC